# iOS-App crashes on touch of inputbox(UITextfield)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uitextfield

I am using custom keyboard for webview by hiding the default keyboard. But my code is crashing whenever I tap on inputbox. It says

```
-[UITextInteractionAssistant containerIsTextField]: message sent to deallocated
```

After a lot of debugging I found out that  [self.view endEditing:YES]; is reposnsible for UITextInteractionAssistant.

Can anyone help in this?

Help in advance!!!

---

```
// register for keyboard show event
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
 object:nil];
```

**hiding UIWebviewAccessary**

```
 -(void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    [self removeBar];
    [self performSelector:@selector(adjustFrame) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.03];
}

- (void)adjustFrame {
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.scroll(0,0)"];
}

- (void)removeBar {
    // Locate non-UIWindow.
    UIWindow *keyboardWindow = nil;
    for (UIWindow *testWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
        if (![[testWindow class] isEqual:[UIWindow class]]) {
            keyboardWindow = testWindow;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Locate UIWebFormView.
    for (UIView *possibleFormView in [keyboardWindow subviews]) {
        // iOS 5 sticks the UIWebFormView inside a UIPeripheralHostView.
        if ([[possibleFormView description] rangeOfString:@"UIPeripheralHostView"].location != NSNotFound) {
            for (UIView *subviewWhichIsPossibleFormView in [possibleFormView subviews]) {
                if ([[subviewWhichIsPossibleFormView description] rangeOfString:@"UIWebFormAccessory"].location != NSNotFound) {
                    [subviewWhichIsPossibleFormView removeFromSuperview];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not able to understood.You have mentioned [self.view endEditing:YES]; is responsible for crash.But this is still present on your given code.Have you tried using endEditing:NO.

Comment: If I comment[self.view endEditing:YES];, then App is not crashing but is also showing native keyboard, which is not desired requirement. As I need to custom keyboard.